# Check input email and suggest a correct domain if there typing mistake

Tags: apex, lightning-inputfield

There is a email lightning input. Let's say User will input a value for that as below.

```
Ex1- test@gimail.com (gimail should correct by giving a suggestion as gmail)
Ex2- test@gamil.co(.co should suggest as .com)
```

I have couple of domain list(Ex-gmail.com) in apex. Is there any way we can check user input domain and check that with the exist domain apex list I have,  whether there is a closer value of input ,If so suggest it as above examples?
(Kind of pattern check with input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a method in Apex you can use, getLevenshteinDistance, which returns the number of deletions, insertions, or substitutions required to convert one string into another. So, one could conceivably write:

```
public String getSuggestion(String domain) {
  Set<String> domainSuggestions = new Set<String> {
    'gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'hotmail.com'
  };
  for(String suggestion: domainSuggestions) {
    if(domain.getLevenshteinDistance(suggestion, 1) > -1) {
      return suggestion;
    }
  }
  return domain;
}
```

You can change the `1` to the desired maximum distance; here, 1 will match `gmail.co` => `gmail.com`, but would not match `gmiail.co`, which should have a threshold of 2.

You could also use something like [fastest-levenshtein](https://github.com/ka-weihe/fastest-levenshtein/tree/master) to implement this completely in client-side code if you wanted to.

Comment: Thank You @sfdcfox.Let me try this and get back to you.